# How do i setup my Junit runner for cucumber to run on multiple projects?

Tags: api, junit, frameworks, cucumber, runner

I recently started working with cucumber where I just set up the project
[project setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkzps.png)

As you can see I have the DefaultRunner.java which is the JUnit runner class and it has the following code:

```
package Runners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src\\test\\resources\\Features\\GreatCourse.feature",
        glue={"Steps"},
        format = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber"},
        tags= {"@smoke"}
        )

public class DefaultRunner {

}
```

Now I can run this from a windows system without any problem but I can't cun this from a Mac because of the addressing system. I tried using an if statement to select the os but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Have you tried: features = "src/test/resources/Features/GreatCourse.feature"?

Comment: I could use that, but that will mean that I can only use it on a mac and not and windows machine. I want to be able to write a single line of code and able to use it on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the "classpath" for the location of the feature file, which should also run on Windows:

```
package Runners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "classpath:Features/GreatCourse.feature",
    glue={"Steps"},
    format = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber"},
    tags= {"@smoke"}
)

public class DefaultRunner {

}
```

I cannot test this because I do not have a Windows machine but should work.